# Включение/выключение переменной в php

Tags: php

Есть скрипт:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $ip;
```

Нужно сделать чтоб в конфиге была возможность включение и выключение отображения переменной.
Пробовал добавить `$ip = false;`, что бы переменная не отображалась - не получилось.

Comment: Так рубильником же.

Answer (score 5):

А условиe никак?

```
$run = true;

if ($run) {

   $ip = $__SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

   echo $ip; 
}
```

Comment: Слишком громоздко, но если по-другому нельзя, то ладно. Спасибо.

Comment: Вариант покороче:  

    if ($run) echo $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ip = true;

 if ($ip) echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: Вот это не плохо. Спасибо, няша :3

Comment: @gm-111, а Вы из этих?

Comment: Извращенцы. Вы бы ещё это предложили

    $ip = true;
    echo $ip ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';

Comment: @ReinRaus, из каких?
@zenith, не, ну это вообще ерунда же.